# @Autowired not able to inject bean in class under test

Tags: java, spring, junit4

I am doing unit test on a class which contains a variable that is `@Autowired` by spring.
However, when I run the test, I get a `NullPointerException` indicating object `userDetailsLoader` is null.

Following is what I have:

```
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsLoader userDetailsLoader;

    public void doSomething (){...}

}
```

JUnit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class UserServiceTest {

    UserService service = new UserService();

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {...}
}
```

UserServiceTest-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="userDetailsLoader" class="my.package.UserDetailsLoader" />

</beans>
```

The configuration file is properly named and there is no `FileNotFoundException`. Can anybody see the problem here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like the class cannot be found. Are you sure this configuration file is used to execute your unit tests?

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Where are you using the `UserService` bean?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I can see in the console it is defining beans [userDetailsLoader, .....] root of context hierarchy. That means the file is for testing right?

Comment: Oh, you're using a direct class instead of using an interface. It would be better using interfaces in tests.

Comment: How are you calling UserServiceTest? How are you calling userService in your test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess I am just being dumb on Monday, still recovering from ending of weekends.

The problem is simple and obvious. I am creating a bean that is not managed by Spring since I wrote `UserService service = new UserService();` in the test calss. In order for a bean to be injected by spring, spring has to be aware of it and has relevant information of it. In my case, I have the config ready (relevant info), but the bean is not injected by Spring (not `@Autowired`).

In conclusion, changing `UserService service = new UserService();` to

`@Autowired UserService service;` solved the problem.